# Regex - matching all between second set of brackets ([])

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string that I need to match only the last seven digets between [] brackets. The string looks like this

> [15211Z: 2012-09-12] ([5202900])

I only need to match 5202900 in the string contained between ([]), a similar number could appear anywhere in the string so something like this won't work `(\d{7})`

I also tried the following regex

> ([[0-9]{1,7}])

but this includes the [] in the string?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV - Using regex together with PHP

Comment: Use `(?<=\[)\d{7}(?=\])`, [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lC8kA5).

Comment: If there is 1, to 7 digits, you just have to replace `{7}` with `{1,7}`

Comment: if the digits are enclosed between `([])` then you can make it stricter , `(?<=\(\[)\d{7}(?=\]\))` [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xM1iU9).

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I think using a group is a lot less complex, and makes for a more readable regular expression.

Comment: @owlstead You're absolutely right especially since he's using php, I'm just playing and honing my regex-fu :)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV well, it is answering the question and does not require a bit of a code change as my answer does, seems your fu is working :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the 7 digits, not the brackets, but want to make sure that the digits are surrounded with brackets:

```
(?<=\[)\d{7}(?=\])
```

FYI: This is called a *positive lookahead* and *positive lookbehind*.

Good source on the topic: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @HamZa DzCyberDeV: thanks for pointing that out! I corrected it now... that's the problem when writing too quickly ;-)

Comment: Lookahead and lookbehind can be **very** expensive. It is better to avoid them if possible. Best method is to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

Try matching `\(\[(\d{7})\]\)`, so you match this whole regular expression, then you take group 1, the one between unescaped parentheses. You can replace `{7}` with a '*' for zero or more, `+` for 1 or more or a precise range like you already showed in your question.

Comment: Note that this matches more than just the numbers, but it makes it easy to retrieve the number without making the regular expression unnecessarily complex (e.g. using positive look-ahead or look-behind). Groups are much more used than those.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to  use

```
\[(\d{1,7})\]
```

Answer (score 0):

If first pattern looks like yours (not only digits), then this should work for you to extract group of digits surrounded by brackets like `([123])`:

```
\(\[(\d+)\]\)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your details, lookbehind and lookaround seems to be good one. You can also use this one:

```
(\d{7})\]\)$
```

Since the pattern of seven digit is expected at the end of the line, engine need to work less in order to find the match.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a benchmark (in Perl, but I think is close the same in php) that compares lookaround approach and capture group:

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = q/[15211Z: 2012-09-12] ([5202900])/;
my $count = -3;
cmpthese($count, {
        'lookaround' => sub {
            $str =~ /(?<=\[)\d{7}(?=\])/;
        },
        'capture group' => sub {
            $str =~ /\[(\d{7})\]/;
        },
    });
```

**result:**

```
                  Rate    lookaround capture group
lookaround    274914/s            --          -70%
capture group 931043/s          239%            --
```

As we can see, capture is more than 3 times faster than lookaround.